# Finding period of a function? Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

I need to find the period of the function $$\large{\frac{\sin (\sin {nx})}{\tan{\frac{x}{n}}}}$$.

According to me, the period of $\sin (\sin (nx))$ should be $\large{\frac{2\pi}{n}}$ and the period of $\large{\tan{\frac{x}{n}}}$ should be $\large{\frac{\pi}{\frac{1}{n}}=\pi n}$.

So the period should be the LCM, that is $\color{red}{\large{2\pi n}}$, right?

But Wolfram Alpha says the function is not periodic. What is the mistake I'm making here?

Comment: Alpha probably doesn't realize that $n$ is an integer parameter; if it isn't at least rational, then the function _isn't_ periodic (because $2\pi/n$ and $\pi n$ aren't commensurate).  If you pick _specific_ values of $n$ then you should find the function to be periodic.  (Also, be careful: the LCM of $2\pi/n$ and $\pi n$ isn't necessarily $2\pi n$ - what happens, for instance, if $n=2$?)

Comment: Isn't that because wolfram is getting confused by the $n$?

Comment: Ah yes, I used $n=3$ and got $6\pi$.

Comment: Is it periodic?  When I graph "y = sin(sin(654 * x)) / tan(x / 654)" into google it "sort of looks" periodic, but not really.  It seems to me, that perhaps your definition of periodic is different from what periodic really means...even so couldn't you just set the equation to $0$ and find the zeros to help find the period???